# Break on test failure in WebStorm debugger?

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way to debug tests in WebStorm so that the debugger breaks (pauses) when a test fails? I've tried activating "Break on Exception" but this doesn't work, or at least not reliably.

On a similar note, adding `--bail` to the run config has no effect.

Comment: no, there is no such feature; you can try playing with conditional breakpoints

Comment: I suppose I could wrap my entire test suite in a try/catch and debug on an assertion error!